# Determine limits of the following sequences and prove

Tags: limits

The two sequences are $a_n = \frac{n}{n^2 + 1}$
and $s_n = \frac{1}{n} \sin(n)$.

I sort of know what do here

Obviously $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=0$, and you can do some sidework and say

$$\left|\frac{n}{n^2 + 1} - 0 \right| = \frac{|n|}{|n^2 + 1|} < \epsilon$$

Dont really know where to go from here.

I am wondering if n has to be a natural number.

Comment: Are you talking about the limit as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: yes most likely since they are sequences

Comment: How are post correctly written in mathematical form?

Comment: Learn how to use LaTeX. If that is too hard, then at least include parentheses for clarity, and then someone else can rewrite it with LaTeX for you.

Answer (score 2):

We want to find 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n^2+1}.$$
The limit is obviously $0$, and it seems to me that saying any more is a waste of time.

However, if we want to practice $\epsilon$-$N$ language, which can be useful elsewhere, we want to show that for ant $\epsilon\gt 0$ there is an $N$ such that if $n\get N$ then 
$$\left|\frac{n}{n^2+1}-0\right|\lt \epsilon.$$
Note that $0\lt \frac{n}{n^2+1}\lt \frac{1}{n}$. It follows that if $n$ is any integer greater than $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$, then $\frac{n}{n^2+1}\lt \epsilon$.

So we can take $N=\left\lceil \frac{1}{\epsilon}\right\rceil$, where $\lceil x\rceil$ is the ceiling function.

The second problem is essentially the same. The limit is clearly $0$, since $\sin(n)$ stays between $-1$ and $1$, and the $n$ at the bottom crushes it.  Formally, we want to show that for every $\epsilon\gt 0$ there is an $N$ such that if $n\gt N$ then
$$\left|\frac{\sin(n)}{n}-0\right|\lt \epsilon.$$
We observe that $\left|\frac{\sin(n)}{n}\right|\le \frac{1}{n}$ and finish like before.

Comment: this explanation perfect, thank you very much

Comment: You are welcome. The "algebra" is often more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

For the first sequence $a_n$, note that

$$a_n=\frac{n}{n^2+1}=\frac{n/n}{(n^2+1)/n}=\frac{1}{n+1/n}.$$

So as $n\to\infty$, since $\frac{1}{n}\to0$, then $n+\frac{1}{n}\to\infty$, and thus

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n+1/n}=0.$$

For the second sequence $b_n$, note that $0\leq|\sin(n)|\leq1$. As $n\to\infty$, $n$ is eventually positive, so:

$$0\leq \left|\frac{1}{n}\sin(n)\right|\leq \frac{1}{n}$$

Using the squeeze theorem, because $\frac{1}{n}\to0$ then $\left|\frac{1}{n}\sin(n)\right|\to0$ also, therefore $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sin(n)=0$.